# Content cannot be displayed

Tags: html, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to include a file (that's in html) inside of my HTML code. When i test it by opening it in my browser i can view the text fine, however when I upload it it does not appear. In chrome nothing appears and in IE it says that this content cannot be displayed.

```
<p><object src="resume-kylerschnaible.html"><embed src="resume-kylerschnaible.html" height="1300px"></embed></object></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rd7yqo6m/

Comment: body tag is not closed??

Answer (score 0):

HTML isn't really the tool of choice for including files, there are countless security settings that are dependent upon browser and server configuration so these kind of include methods are generally seen as unreliable. I would suggest moving to php or asp.net if you need this kind of functionality. Failing that you might find that the iframe method is slightly more flexible.

```
<iframe src="resume-kylerschnaible.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just decided to go with the iframe method but still come across the same problem in my original question. Do you have any idea why this is not working on my uploaded version?